# Backups behaving strangely (16.10)

Tags: backup, 16.10, duplicity

I installed ubuntu 2 weeks ago. I set the option to make a backup once a day.
*But* it always gave me an error saying something like "gi.repository not found". A few days ago somehow the process went without a hitch. This only happened once, now I get this.

[image]

How am I supposed to fix this?

Comment: Weird, it should have been installed, but what if you run `sudo apt install python3-gi python-gi`?

Comment: I just ran that command, python-gi  wasn't installed. Maybe it's because I messed up badly like two days after installing and I had to reinstall the system (I used the option to keep my files so maybe it's that).

Comment: Aha, curious if it works now?

Comment: @JacobVlijm     Running that plus sudo apt install duplicity        (sorry I don't know how to use that effect) fixed this, thanks.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  Go ahead, I'll make it the accepted one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### gi.repository

The fact that you got the message that `gi.repository` is missing makes me believe that the application is written in `python` (either `python2` or `python3` *and* that you are missing `python-gi` or `python3-gi`. Both should be on your system though.

#### Fix it

You can probably fix it by running:

```
sudo apt install python-gi python3-gi
```

(since we don't know which version is used), but to make sure all dependencies are installed correctly, you might as well completely re-install `duplicity`

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni don't mention it, glad it works!